# Building two .exe files in C# One 32 bit and the other 64 bit

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, 32bit-64bit

I am working on something that requires the program to build as 32bit and 64 bit. So basically I want a 32bit MyProgram.exe and then MyProgram.x64.exe in my folder when I build the whole thing. Is this possible? I am not sure how to do this. When I just build it, it just builds a 64 bit MyProgram.exe because I am running on a 64 bit machine, but I want two exe files. Is this even possible? I am using Visual Studio 2013 express, I am not sure how to mess with the settings to do this. Or something that has to do inside my code?

Comment: Why not take advantage of build properties of the project..?

Comment: You should use something like [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: "it just builds a 64 bit MyProgram.exe *because* I am running on a 64 bit machine" - this is not true... By default C# compiles "AnyCPU" irrespective of host processor (and in addition it does "prefer 32bit" by default). You may want to clarify why you need x64/x86 variants (i.e. "I use native library that comes with 32/64 versions" or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it by the click of the button, you need to specify to build it as a post-build event.

If you use Visual Studio Premier+, you can use Build->Batch Build to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can build 64 bit or 32 bit versions of programs by setting up several build configurations:

> Build -> Configuration Manager ...

Set the "Active solution platform:" to either x86 or x64 as appropriate.

Each build will have to go into it's own set of output folders but you can create a post build step to copy the exe (and any other files) where ever you need it to be.

Then, while developing and debugging you can pick the appropriate target and build both configurations when you want to release a new version.

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a JIT'd language, you can tell the JIT compiler which platform you prefer, but it's technically up to the JIT compiler.  The .exe files on your disk are [MS]IL and not an actual executable in any specific platform as you might get with a C/C++ compiler.

This of course assumes you haven't done anything special such as run NGen or other post-processor.